# how to check if firebase have value1 and value2 exist

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to do the following in my `Android` application using `Kotlin` :

I have the Firebase data structure as shown in this image:

[image]

The user is able to choose 2 stations from the stations included in the data, either as "start_station", "end_station" or "station_number".. in the next function am trying to take the user's selections and check if both are encluded in the same line.

```
    private fun fetchingLinesData(
        theEndStation: String,
        theStartStation: String,
    ) {
        val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        val myRef = database.getReference("line")
        myRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                toast(getString(R.string.could_not_find_a_way))
            }

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
               p0.children.forEach{
               //Here should be the line that checks if both data exist
            }
           }
        })
    }
```

Tried using [This hasChild Method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot.html#haschild) but it wasn't right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to convert your response to `HashMap` and search using `containsValue`

```
override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
    p0.children.forEach {
        //Here should be the line that checks if both data exist

        if(it.hasChildren()) {
            val stationLines = it.value as HashMap<String, Any>
            val validStart = stationLines.containsValue(theStartStation)
            val validEnd = stationLines.containsValue(theEndStation)

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a query:

```
myRef.orderByChild("end_station").equalTo(theEndStation).addValueEventListener
```

This will retrieve the data according to the query, then inside `onDataChange()` after the `forEach` you can do the following:

```
if(p0.exists()){
// retrieve data here
}
```

Using `exists()` you can check if the datasnapshot exists.

---

This query will only check for `end_station`, if you want to check both, then after the query inside the if statement you can retrieve the `first_station`:

```
if(p0.exists()){
val firstStation = it.child("start_station").value
```

And check if `firstStation` is equal to `theStartStation`